# Can't flatten JSON array to prepare for CSV conversion using Ruby 2.1.4

Tags: arrays, ruby, json, csv

I have an array of nested JSON "hash" objects that I need to completely flatten so it ports over to CSV cleanly, which is obviously not nested and "multidimensional" like JSON typically is.

But the flatten method (used here with ! bang) is not working (it creates the file with no error but then the file is empty).

In my ruby file below I leave a working example of commented out code which isjust doing a simply conversion without the .flatten method. Since the JSON is an array (at the highest level) - separated by commas and enclosed in square brackets, shouldn't it take the .flatten method, just as it takes .each in the working commented out block? (This is also what the docs seems to indicate!)

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

# CSV.open('false-hotels-merged.csv', 'w') do |csv|
#   JSON.parse(File.open('monfri-false-hotels-merged.json').read).each do |hash|
#     csv << hash.values
#   end
# end

CSV.open('wed-all-false-hotels.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  JSON.parse(File.open('monfri-false-hotels-merged.json').read).flatten! do |f|
    csv << f.values
  end
end
```

Example JSON data snippet:

```
[...
        {
          "id": "111707",
          "name": "Seven Park Place by William Drabble",
          "phone": "+442073161600",
          "email": "restaurant@stjameshotelandclub.com",
          "website": "http://www.stjameshotelandclub.com/michelin-star-chef-william-drabble",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 51.5062548,
            "longitude": -0.1403209,
            "address": {
              "line1": "7-8 Park Place",
              "line2": "St James's",
              "line3": "",
              "postcode": "SW1A 1LP",
              "city": "London",
              "country": "UK"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "104493",
          "name": "Seymour's Restaurant & Bar",
          "phone": "+442079352010",
          "email": "reservations@theleonard.com",
          "website": "http://www.theleonard.com",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 51.51463,
            "longitude": -0.15779,
            "address": {
              "line1": "15 Seymour Street",
              "line2": "",
              "line3": "",
              "postcode": "W1H 7JW",
              "city": "London",
              "country": "UK"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "250922",
          "name": "Shaka Zulu",
          "phone": "+442033769911",
          "email": "info@shaka-zulu.com",
          "website": "http://www.shaka-zulu.com/",
          "location": {
            "latitude": 51.5414979,
            "longitude": -0.1458655,
            "address": {
              "line1": "Stables Market ",
              "line2": "Camden",
              "line3": "",
              "postcode": "NW1 8AB",
              "city": "London",
              "country": "UK"
            }
          }
        }
    ]
```

Again, no errors at all in the terminal - just blank CSV file created.

Comment: try using `wb` when opening csv for writing

Comment: On second thoughts probably flatten isn't the best method to use, the format for how I think the JSON needs to look to be ready for CSV is in this gist: https://gist.github.com/daneasterman/5b49c30b85d33fced965

Comment: Well, yeah. As @Martin mentioned in this answer - nested hash need different approach.

Comment: any idea what approach I need to use @konart?

Comment: The very first thing that comes to mind is to create you own hash object with keys you need and map it with json object's key values while unpacking nested hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

def hflat(h)
  h.values.flat_map {|v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? hflat(v) : v }
end

CSV.open('file.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  JSON.parse(File.open('file.json').read).each do |h| 
    csv << hflat(h)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is great @mario-zannone, it works brilliantly! But can you break down the hflat method a bit - I don't understand all the syntax - ie. teach a man to fish and all that! - thanks!

Comment: Well, `hflat` converts an hash (`h`) in an array of values, reapplying itself recursively for each value that is an hash itself. The code uses the ruby 2.x array function flat_map that is more or less equivalent to  array.map {...}.flatten. Check the ruby 2.x docs for details.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) only flattens arrays. There is also [`Hash#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-flatten), which also produces an array. You seem to want to flatten a nested Hash for which I don't know of a library method.

It seems that your result is empty because there's an `.each` missing after the `flatten` - the block is simply not run.